# Chromonema and Chromonemata

Tags: dna

A chromonemata is composed of two chromonema. Which are again composed of chromatin fibre. Thus my question is chromonemata is composed of how many chromatin fibre ?

Comment: It's the opposite: singular -> chromonema, plural -> chromonemata.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, a chromonema is the filament of DNA constituting a chromosome during interphase; its equivalent during DNA replication is chromatid. The plural of chromonema is chromonemata.

The chromatin is the form in which DNA is found within the nucleus of a eukaryotic cell, that is in complex with proteins such as histones.